# React Native - Responsive image widths (percentages?)

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a responsive photo grid built within a RN app -

[image]

I'd like 3 images to fit across the screen with the respective margin guttering.  All images are squares.

I'm after some tips on the best way to achieve this - i'd use percentages in a web build for each image square but understand this isnt a possibility in RN..

This is what I have so Far:
The code basically pulls images out of an array via a map function and adds the grey image upload button at the same size after them as below:

```
     <View style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnailWrap}>
            {this.state.ADImageArray.map((prop, key) => {

               return (
                  <Image
                    source={{uri: prop, isStatic: true}}
                    style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnail}
                    />
               );
            })}
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.photoAdditional} >
            <View style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbAddMore}>
              <Image source={require('../images/icons/ico-upload- 
               photo.png')} style={PhotoStyles.imgThumbnailBtn} />
            </View>
      </View>
```

Heres the Styles:

```
imgThumbnailWrap: {
  flex:1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  flexWrap:'wrap',
},
imgThumbnail: {
  backgroundColor:'#f79431',
  width:100,
  height:100,
  margin:8,
},
imgThumbAddMore: {
  width:100,
  height:100,
  margin:8,
  backgroundColor: '#e9e9e9',
  alignItems:'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
```

},

As you can see the two image classes (imgThumbnail and imgThumbAddMore) have fixed widths in the above example - i'd like to make them fit in a row of 3 width percentage widths and height based on the width of the parent container (imgThumbnailWrap).  Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide the width of the device and subtract the margin on the outside

```
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

const padding = 10
const itemWidth = (Dimensions.get('window').width / 3) - (padding * 4)
```

Use the `itemWidth` with both the width and height so you get perfect squares.

Comment: thanks for your help @moritzw - The calculations don't seem to work though - unless i'm missing something - i have 10 margin on the thumbs - so with 3 across that would equate to subtracting 20 for each  (rather than 40 in your code above).  I've changed and it works - the screen width of my iPhone is 375, alerting the calculated width as 105 (x3 + 60 = 375) which is perfect - but they only fit on one line if i reduce the item margib to 8 for some bizzare reason...!?

Comment: @moitzw - i'm going to give your answer a green tick - as it was 95% correct and really helpful - i'll raise the other issue separately as i think its a separate to whats asked in the above question.  Thans very much for your help..

Answer (score 1):

This problem can easily solve by using paddingTop, width, and position. Just try the below code.

```
<View style={{width:'100%',paddingTop:'100%'}}>
  <Image source={{uri:url}} style={{position:'absolute',left:0,bottom:0,right:0,top:0,resizeMode:'contain'}} />
 </View>
```